# SQL Creating a cloumn in a view with the results from cross-referencing two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, case, parentheses

I'm new to SQL and was attempting to create a view that combines data from a database of readings and from a database of failures. I wanted to create a view ordered by target name, then metric name, then by timestamp, with an additional column that returns a 1 to say there was a failure on that day and a zero otherwise. The query I've written is currently reading that I'm missing a right parenthesis, but when I eliminate the parenthesis it finds the table names invalid. I'm unsure whether my use of case is causing it, although it has worked on some practice samples. Any help checking this and suggestions on how to improve it would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
with new_failure_table as  (
    SELECT target_name, END_TIMESTAMP,START_TIMESTAMP, 
    ((END_TIMESTAMP - (START_TIMESTAMP))*24*60) 
    FROM failure_table 
    WHERE (END_TIMESTAMP - (START_TIMESTAMP))*24*60 >5 
    AND  (END_TIMESTAMP - START_TIMESTAMP) < 1
    and availability_status = 'Target Down'
    ) 
    -- Simplifies failure table to include actual failures according to two parameters

SELECT
    t1.target_name,
    t1.metric_name,
    t1.rollup_timestamp,
    t1.average,
    t1.minimum,
    t1.maximum,
    t1.standard_deviation,
    t2.END_TIMESTAMP,
    t2.START_TIMESTAMP,
    (CASE  
    when t1.target_name = t2.target_name 
    and t1.rollup_timestamp = trunc(END_TIMESTAMP+1) 
    and t1.rollup_timestamp = trunc(START_TIMESTAMP+1) 
    THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS failure_status
    --Used to create column that reads 1 when there was a failure between the two readings and 0 otherwise    

FROM
    data_readings AS t1, new_failure_table AS t2 
WHERE t1.target_name = t2.target_name       
)

GROUP BY t1.target_name, metric_name
ORDER BY rollup_timestamp desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to wrap `case` in parenthesis instead it can be

```
CASE  
when t1.target_name = t2.target_name 
and t1.rollup_timestamp = trunc(END_TIMESTAMP+1) 
and t1.rollup_timestamp = trunc(START_TIMESTAMP+1) 
THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS failure_status
```

Also in `FROM` do not use `AS` instead of:

```
...
FROM data_readings AS t1, new_failure_table AS t2 
...
```

use

```
...
FROM data_readings t1, new_failure_table t2 
...
```

UPD: The whole query should look like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
with new_failure_table as  (
    SELECT target_name, END_TIMESTAMP,START_TIMESTAMP, 
    ((END_TIMESTAMP - (START_TIMESTAMP))*24*60) 
    FROM failure_table 
    WHERE (END_TIMESTAMP - (START_TIMESTAMP))*24*60 >5 
    AND  (END_TIMESTAMP - START_TIMESTAMP) < 1
    and availability_status = 'Target Down'
    ) 
    -- Simplifies failure table to include actual failures according to two parameters

SELECT
    t1.target_name as target_name,
    t1.metric_name as metric_name,
    t1.rollup_timestamp as rollup_timestamp,
    t1.average,
    t1.minimum,
    t1.maximum,
    t1.standard_deviation,
    t2.END_TIMESTAMP,
    t2.START_TIMESTAMP,
    CASE  
    when t1.target_name = t2.target_name 
    and t1.rollup_timestamp = trunc(END_TIMESTAMP+1) 
    and t1.rollup_timestamp = trunc(START_TIMESTAMP+1) 
    THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS failure_status
    --Used to create column that reads 1 when there was a failure between the two readings and 0 otherwise    

FROM
    data_readings t1, new_failure_table t2 
WHERE t1.target_name = t2.target_name       
)
GROUP BY target_name, metric_name
ORDER BY rollup_timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Hi Hatik, the parenthesis error is now on line 28, which I think is just above the GROUP BY function. I'm unsure as all parenthesise seem to match up.

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark try to move the parenthesis that is about `group by ` after the `order by `

Comment: Weirdly, same error same line after moving it. If it says missing right parenthesis does a function elsewhere need parenthesise?

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark btw what is the db engine are you using, is it Oracle?

Comment: The db engine I am using is Oracle

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark not exactly, not sure how to explain though. I also noticed that you are using `FROM
    data_readings AS t1, new_failure_table AS t2 ` which is wrong, when using `FROM` you do not need `AS` it should be `FROM
    data_readings t1, new_failure_table t2 `

Comment: Good call. I removed the AS cases. The error now reads '%s: invalid identifier' for the GROUP BY function. Do I need the "t1." label, as when I remove it the error reads "not a GROUP BY expression"?

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark I have updated my answer, can you try that one?

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark did it work? If not that means that your data cannot be grouped by your `group by` and needs the revision

Comment: I've tried the revised code and it says the "table or view does not exist". Ok, by needs revision do you mean the kind of data I'm grouping it by?

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark by revision I mean revision of code according to the data you have in your DB, as for the error it means that it really cannot find the tables with your provided names, you have to check if the table name is written correctly in the code and if it is really existing in your database

Comment: That makes sense, and the code you've provided will provide a great template for when I've checked it.

Comment: @AlwaysInTheDark glad to hear that it was helpful